# How do I perform a full join in ARel?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, arel

Assume I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB` with a many-to-many relationship through a joining table `TableABJoin`. I would like to use ARel 3 to generate a query that performs a full join of `TableA` and `TableB`.

The query I want to generate should be something along these lines:

```
SELECT a.id, b.code
FROM TableA as a, TableB as b
```

This results in a full join of tables A and B.

The closest I have been able to get, without writing an explicit sql string, is to hack an outer join:

```
part_a = TableA.arel_table
part_b = TableB.arel_table
query = part_a.join(part_b, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on('1=1').project(part_a[:id], part_b[:code]).to_sql
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "TableA"."id", "TableB"."code" FROM "TableA" LEFT OUTER JOIN "TableB" ON 1=1
```

If I exclude the `.on` component I end up with a trailing NULL:

```
SELECT "TableA"."id", "TableB"."code" FROM "TableA" LEFT OUTER JOIN "TableB" NULL
```

Is there a more reasonable way to generate a proper full join or at least generate the same result without hacking a left outer join in ARel?

Comment: I'm working on this too, how to perform full outer join?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, is not possible to perform a full outer join (and a right outer join) with arel, which only supports Inner and Outer (LEFT OUTER) joins.

Because I didn't like this, I updated arel 3-0-stable (I'm working on a 3.2.13 rails application) so that it supports right and full outer joins too. Adding those was pretty straightforward even with undocumented code, it's quite easy so you should face no issue if you try it.

Here you can find my pull request: https://github.com/rails/arel/pull/202
And here you can find the updated repository with a branch: https://github.com/Fire-Dragon-DoL/arel/tree/3-0-right-full-outer-join

You can easily use this in a rails application by adding this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'arel', '~> 3.0.3.4', github: 'Fire-Dragon-DoL/arel', branch: '3-0-right-full-outer-join'
```

Here you can see a syntax example:

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cat_diseases
end
class Disease < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cat_diseases
end

class CatDisease < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cat
  belongs_to :disease

  def self.all_diseases_for_cat(cat)
    cat_diseases = self.arel_table
    diseases     = Disease.arel_table

    scoped
    .joins(
      cat_diseases.join(diseases, Arel::Nodes::RightOuterJoin)
                    .on(cat_diseases[:disease_id].eq(diseases[:id]))
      .join_sources
    )
    .where(
      cat_diseases[:cat_id].eq(cat.id)
      .or(cat_diseases[:cat_id].eq(nil))
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, happy to see some feedback, for some reason it went ignored for long time

Answer (score 0):

I write the join in SQL. Its clearer and works fine:

```
part_a = TableA.arel_table
part_b = TableB.arel_table
query = part_a.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "TableB"').other_scopes.to_sql
```